# Magento 2 Newsletter email in spam

Tags: newsletter

I am getting only newsletter email in spam with the sender address like this
Username@ip-111-11-11-111.eu-central-1.compute.internal

What should be the reason ? Please suggest!!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: You need to setup the email addresses on admin panel to get the sender address like username@domain.com

1. Stores -> Configuration -> Store Email Addresses(Under general tab.)
2. Stores -> Configuration -> Contacts(Under general tab.)

Step 2 : To calculate spam score, you need to send the test mail to an email (Ex:  web-4o1yy@mail-tester.com), listed in the http://www.mail-tester.com/

Step 3: Open the [mail-tester](http://www.mail-tester.com), enter an email(Ex: web-4o1yy@mail-tester.com) and check your score. Follow the suggestions to reduce the spam rate.